# Padding so always 12 digits long

Tags: c#

I have an string which needs to be always 12 digits long

Its need starts with 'PSS1'

but need there to be always 12 characters and pad the difference with zero's

so if input is string1 = '300'

I would need the result = 'PSS100000300'

when the input length increase the number of zero padding decreases so the total of characters remains 12.

I've tried using `.padleft` or `.ToString("D12")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
string result = "PSS1".PadRight(12 - string1.Length,'0') + string1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize that your original question said that you had a `string`, but if it were an `int`, you could do this with the `ToString` method on the `int` object.

```
int input = 300;
input.ToString("PSS100000000");
```

Which returns `PSS100000300`

Perhaps doesn't answer this *specific* question, but may potentially be useful for others.